# Android GridView not responding to OnItemClickListener

Tags: android, gridview, onclicklistener

I found that some people had this problem as well, but none of the existing solutions worked for me. Essentially I have an Fragment (called HeadlinesFragment), that assigns an OnItemClickListener to a GridView containing images. The images appear fine, but the touch/click event is never fired. I tried with multiple combinations of android:clickable="false"/android:focusable="false", etc but nothings works for me

```
public static class HeadlinesFragment extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.menufragment, container, false);
        return rootView;
    }

    public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
        private Context context;

        Integer[] imageIDs = {
                R.drawable.pasta05,
                R.drawable.pasta05,
                R.drawable.pasta05,
                R.drawable.pasta05,
                R.drawable.pasta05,
                R.drawable.pasta05,
                R.drawable.pasta05
        };

        public ImageAdapter(Context c) {
            context = c;
        }

        //---returns the number of images---
        public int getCount() {
            return imageIDs.length;
        }

        //---returns the ID of an item---
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        //---returns an ImageView view---
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            ImageView imageView;
            if (convertView == null) {
                imageView = new ImageView(context);
                imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(185, 185));
                imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
                imageView.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
            } else {
                imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
            }
            imageView.setImageResource(imageIDs[position]);
            return imageView;
        }
    }
    GridView gridView;
    @Override
    public  void onActivityCreated (Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         gridView = (GridView) getView().findViewById(R.id.GridView);

        gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "SSSSSX", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                System.out.println("R=");

            }

        });
        gridView.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(getActivity()));
    }
}
```

On the other hand, this is XML for the Fragment containing the GridView:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/GridView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="4dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:numColumns="3"
        android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth" >
    </GridView>
```

And finally, this is the XML containing the main Activity that hosts the Fragment.

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:components="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:background="#0099cc"
tools:context="com.purplemechanics.rest_a_urant.FullscreenActivity">

<!-- The primary full-screen view. This can be replaced with whatever view
     is needed to present your content, e.g. VideoView, SurfaceView,
     TextureView, etc. -->


<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"  android:id="@+id/richardo">


    </LinearLayout>

<!-- This FrameLayout insets its children based on system windows using
     android:fitsSystemWindows. -->


    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <RelativeLayout
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            tools:context=".MainActivity" >


            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:text="Large Text"
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="112dp" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/list_view"
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:background="#007095"
            android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
            android:divider="#005875"
            android:dividerHeight="2dp"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            />
    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: did you ever get this fixed?

Answer (score 0):

Try instantiating with `new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()` like following:

```
gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "SSSSSX", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            System.out.println("R=");

        }

    });
```

Comment: The problem persists